# DUDA - Mars Rover challenge

Tags: javascript

No sé si conocéis el Mars Rover Challenge, supongo que sí. Tengo funciones para que se mueva, para que gire y para que vuelva hacia atrás.

Tengo que añadir obstáculos, y que si se topa con ellos, no avance.

En la función de avanzar tengo lo siguiente:

```
function moveForward(roverDirection){
//Comprobamos hacia donde mira el Rover, y movemos en esa dirección
  switch(roverDirection){
    case 'N':
    if(checkObstacle([rover.x, rover.y])){
      rover.y--;
    }
    break;

    case 'W':
    if(checkObstacle([rover.x, rover.y])){
      rover.x--;
    }
    break;

    case 'S':
    if(checkObstacle([rover.x, rover.y])){
      rover.y++;
    }
    break;

    case 'E':
    if(checkObstacle([rover.x, rover.y])){
      rover.x++;
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

Antes de mover el rover, usamos la función `checkObstacle` la cual le pasamos el `x` y el `y` del rover.

```
function checkObstacle([x, y]){
  var direction = rover.direction;

  if(direction === 'N'){
    if([x,y - 1] === 'obstacle'){
      console.log('Ups!');
      return false
    }else{
      return true;
    }
  }
  if(direction === 'W'){
    if([x - 1 ,y] === 'obstacle'){
      console.log('Ups!');
      return false
    }else{
      return true;
    }
  }
  if(direction === 'S'){
    if([x,y + 1] === 'obstacle'){
      console.log('Ups!');
      return false
    }else{
      return true;
    }
  }
  if(direction === 'E'){
    if([x + 1,y] === 'obstacle'){
      console.log('Ups!');
      return false
    }else{
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

No sé como debo de vincular esta funcion con el grid que es una array bidimensional:

```
var grid = [
  ['rover', 'obstacle' , null , null, null, 'obstacle', null, null, null, null],
  [null, null , null , null, null, null, 'obstacle', null, null, null],
  [null, null , 'obstacle' , null, null, null, null, null, null, 'obstacle'],
  [null, null , null , null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
  ['obstacle', null , null , null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
  [null, null , null , null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
  [null, null , null , null, 'obstacle', null, null, null, null, null],
  [null, null , null , null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
  [null, null , null , null, null, null, null, null, null, 'obstacle'],
  [null, null , null , null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
];
```

Como debo de proceder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entiendo que el valor X sería la posición del array padre e Y la posicion en el array hijo elegido por X.

En ese caso solo tendrías que modificar las condiciones if de tu funcion `checkObstacle` para obtener el valor del array

```
function checkObstacle([x, y]){
  var direction = rover.direction;

  if(direction === 'N'){
    if(grid[x][y - 1] === 'obstacle'){
      console.log('Ups!');
      return false
    }else{
      return true;
    }
  }

  [...]
```

Como añadido puedes hacer tu código más óptimo utilizando un operador ternario:

```
function checkObstacle([x, y]){
  var direction = rover.direction;

  if(direction === 'N'){
    return grid[x][y - 1] === 'obstacle' ? false : true;
  }

  [...]
```

Comment: Genial!!! muchísimas gracias David. No sabía como vincularlo con el grid, y es de lo mas tonto! :P gracias de nuevo.